# which storage type is good for large data when using dcc.Store()

Tags: plotly-dash

when using dcc.Store() for large data, which storage type is good, memory, local or session?

I got an error of

```
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)
```

The webpage also crashes showing below figure:

[image]

Comment: How large data (order of magnitude) are we talking about?

Comment: json file size is 3GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are limitations to using `dcc.Store`. It stores the data in the browser, which is not ideal or even intended for large/very large datasets, as performance issues will arise. Here is a [list](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store#storage-limitations) of those limitations for the component.

If you intend to use visualise large datasets using Dash, I recommend a great tool that combines Django with Dash called [django-plotly-dash](https://django-plotly-dash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Essentially, you'll be handling the backend all in django using its model-view approach, and then building your dashboard in dash that will be integrated with the django backend. So rather than using `dcc.Store` to store any large datasets, you can query your database in the callbacks, hence visualising large datasets more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

this component is not for storing large datasets... It's a good component to store some data that will be used through the application;

Also, Dash is not a good framework for big data projects like the one you did mention.

If you need some extra help feel free to message me pvt.

Comment: I don’t agree with the claim that Dash is not a good framework for big data projects. If you setup your infrastructure appropriately, a Dash front end can be used to visualize data of any size.

Comment: Hey @ember I would appreciate it a lot if you could provide any reference about what you're talking about... I have a lot of experience building dash apps for companies and almost always reach a point where it starts to have very poor performance as taking a lot of time to render charts or to propagate the data between the app; And please, do not understand me bad, I love Dash and I use it a lot, but it has pros and cons;

Comment: I think an extended discussion is beyond the scope of comments, but some example are dash holoviews (https://github.com/plotly/dash-holoviews-taxi) that explores a 10 million row dataset, the dash terracotta stack (https://github.com/thedirtyfew/terracotta-dash-example) that I have used for visualizing GB-size datasets, WebGL chart types (https://plotly.com/python/webgl-vs-svg/) and dash-leaflet marker cluster (http://dash-leaflet.herokuapp.com/#super_cluster) for point visualizations (I used the latter for + 1 million points) just to mention a few.

Comment: I don't think there's any tool out there that be used to visualize big datasets without making a proper backend connection to a data store.